# Python: How do sets work

Tags: python, hash, set

I have a list of objects which I want to turn into a set. My objects contain a few fields that some of which are `o.id` and `o.area`. I want two objects to be equal if these two fields are the same. ie: `o1==o2` if and only if `o1.area==o2.area and o1.id==o2.id`.

I tried over-writing `__eq__` and `__cmp__` but I get the error: `TypeError: unhashable instance`.

What should I over-write?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset and http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Define the `__hash__` method to return a meaningful hash based on the id and area fields. E.g.:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.id) ^ hash(self.area)
```

Comment: I'm a little leery of bitwise math on something like that. I'd use something like =return hash((self.id, self.area))=.

Comment: This is likely to be a problem when hashing two similar components. For instance hash(x) ^ hash(y) will misbehave if coordinates pair with swapped axes are common. In this case, it is extremely unlikely to cause problems since it is impossible to generate ints and strings with correlated hashes. Having said that, your suggestion is still a good one, which I wish I'd thought of :-).

Answer (score 9):

"TypeError: unhashable instance." error is probably due to old-style class definition i.e.:

```
class A:
  pass
```

Use new style instead:

```
class A(object):
  pass
```

If you override __cmp__ function you **should** override __hash__ for using your object in sets. In the other case hash considers all object instances as unequal and __cmp__ function will never be called.