# What is the correct way to implement a set that checks type in the add method in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to restrict the elements of the set to be instances of a certain class. Should I subclass set and override the add method? How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you may need to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532365/python-how-do-sets-work) and its answers when building a set of custom objects. Briefly, you'll need to define methods such as `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` so that you can add them to a set:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Foo) and self.value == other.value
```

Now you can compare the objects, and the `set` can as well:

```py
In [19]: a = Foo()

In [20]: b = Foo()

In [21]: c = Foo(1)

In [22]: a == b
Out[22]: True

In [23]: b == c
Out[23]: False

In [24]: s = set([a, b, c])

In [25]: s
Out[25]: 
set([<__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f758>,
     <__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f950>])

In [26]: s.add(Foo())

In [27]: s
Out[27]: 
set([<__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f758>,
     <__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f950>])
```

The problem is, you can still add something completely different to the set:

```py
In [28]: s.add(1)

In [29]: s
Out[29]: 
set([<__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f758>,
     <__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f950>,
     1])
```

One way would be to override the `add()` method of `set` as you suggest:

```py
In [30]: class FooSet(set):
   ....:     def add(self, elem):
   ....:         if isinstance(elem, Foo):
   ....:             set.add(self, elem)
   ....:         else:
   ....:             raise TypeError('%s is not a Foo' % elem)
   ....:             # or just put "pass" here for silent behavior

In [31]: s = FooSet([a, b, c])

In [32]: s
Out[32]: 
set([<__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f758>,
     <__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f950>])

In [33]: s.add(Foo())

In [34]: s
Out[34]: 
set([<__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f758>,
     <__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f950>])

In [35]: s.add(Foo(2))

In [36]: s
Out[36]: 
set([<__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f758>,
     <__main__.Foo instance at 0x267f950>,
     <__main__.Foo instance at 0x26808c0>])

In [37]: s.add(2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

...

TypeError: 2 is not a Foo
```